# Fetch/Axios in React Native stops without error

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a working little app on my local box. The setup is React Native, Redux Thunk and Redux. With Thunk, I do load data from my backend server.

This all works pretty fine, except one single request just stops while loading the data. The code looks like:

```
export function readData() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        console.log("service called");

        return axios.get(
              BASE_URL + '/my-data',{ 
              timeout: 120000,
              transformResponse: function(data) {
                console.log("transform");
                return JsonUtils.readJsonFromResponse(data);
              }
            }
          ).then(response => {
            console.log("output");
            dispatch(showData(response.data.result));
          }).catch(error => {
          console.log("error", error);
          throw error;
      });

    }
}
```

The above code is now showing axios, but the same problem occurs with Fetch. When I change the code to another URL, it works just fine. The result is valid. The only difference I see is my other URLs deliver around 5kb of data, while the problematic one currently delivers around 100kb.

The output of the above is:

```
service called
```

When another URL is used, all console outputs are written.

On the server side, I can see the output was written and passed on. It looks like the request was sent successfully, the response was returned, but React does not pick it up.

The funny thing is, sometimes (very rarely) this works as expected with the problematic URL.

I have meanwhile disabled remoted debugging. I work on a Mac and use the iOS simulator, but I have also verified the problem happens on my iPhone 7+.

EDIT: I also played with the timeout (no timeout = 0, very high timeout) and so on. This didn't help. I can see the local (!) server responding very quickly. In my Postman tests, it was a response time of around 100ms.

EDIT2: I am never running into the catch block or see any other error.

EDIT3: Here is the result of the problematic service. Please note, it is valid JSON pre and suffixed with /* */ (historical reasons). As it is now, it can be consumed by many other clients.

```
/* {
    "result": [{
        "tasks": [{
            "id": xxxx,
            "active": true,
            "complete": false,
            "description": "",
            "estimated": null,
            "lastused_at_ts": 1468263101,
            "completed_at_ts": null,
            "created_at_ts": 1322611200,
            "name": "xxxxxx",
            "projectId": xxxxx,
            "projectName": null,
            "taskCategoryId": 1,
            "taskCategoryName": "xxxx.default",
            "uuid": "xxxxxx-8182-47c2-9cd6-8eff216ee714",
            "taskCategory": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "xxxx.default"
            },
            "createdAt": "16.01.1970 07:23",
            "lastUsed": 1468263101,
            "completedAt": "20.04.2018 09:47"
        },
                 ....],
        "times": null,
        "name": "xxxxxx",
        "id": 32,
        "comment": "xxxxx",
        "uuid": "xxxxx-3a00-4e1d-82a1-e72318d5df3f",
        "createdAt": "16.01.1970",
        "active": false
    }, 
               ...
} */
```

Where I added the ..., there are many more data rows to come. The output is usually not pretty printed, it is a single line.

What might cause this problem?

Comment: Can you show us what `my-data` looks like?

Comment: Thanks @Colin for your interest. I added some example response. The original server is written in Java and runs on Tomcat. Since I tested against production and other clients do not face problems, I don't think it's server related.

Comment: You have this: `When another URL is used, all console outputs are written.`. Is this the case when you use another URL returning the same data as the problematic URL?

Comment: No. When I call URLs which return data in a similar size, the request stops too. Only when I call URLs which do return data much smaller, like 5 - 30 kb it wents through.

Comment: Hmm. And does it work if you take out the `transformResponse`?

Comment: No, I actually tried that and removed all unnecessary. It's driving me crazy to be honest. I have thought if I would use thunks wrong, but the above code I wrote with the docs directly next to me :-/

Comment: I think if the size of the data affects behavior that's a good place to start. If you're able to make a codesandbox example I'll take a look.

Comment: Creating such an example will take me a while. Are you up to freelancing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169426/discussion-between-colin-and-christian).

Comment: @Christian did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @Rob When I recall correctly, the request was cached. It's 5 years ago, please pardon to not be able to give a better answer. I also found out a long time after I asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have a `timeout` of `6000`. What's likely happening is that the bigger request (100kb) is taking longer than that to resolve. Try upping the timeout.

Additionally, you should add chain a `.catch()` clause, as you can `console.error()` things like this to help debug them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. I was already playing with timeout and also had a catch. But I never run into the catch and the timeout does not kickin. Actually everything is local so far, I can see the server responding and transmitting very fast.

Comment: @Colin I was using create-native-app which added Expo to my build. I recreated everything with react-native init and since then it looks good. Looks like Expo is breaking something. I am upvoting your answer anyway since your points are all valid and make sense.

Comment: @Christian Strange. Thanks!